# How do you set a scenario when doing a restful call in Yii2 to return certain fields

Tags: angularjs, rest, yii2

Im currently making a Yii2 RESTful system with AngularJs.

In my database i've got several columns that i want to be able to return when doing a particular call from a certain point in my system.

The problem i'm having is how do i return only a handful of fields eg(id, title and stub) from the restful call in another part of my system so that it ignores other fields in the table.

I would ideally like it to work in a similar way to how a Models rules work with scenarios in yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods, I think:

### 1. use params

```
// returns all fields as declared in fields()
http://localhost/users
// only returns field id and email, provided they are declared in fields()
http://localhost/users?fields=id,email
// returns all fields in fields() and field profile if it is in extraFields()
http://localhost/users?expand=profile
// only returns field id, email and profile, provided they are in fields() and extraFields()
http://localhost/users?fields=id,email&expand=profile
```

### 2. overriding model's fields()

```
// explicitly list every field, best used when you want to make sure the changes
// in your DB table or model attributes do not cause your field changes (to keep API backward compatibility).
public function fields()
{
    return [
        // field name is the same as the attribute name
        'id',
        // field name is "email", the corresponding attribute name is "email_address"
        'email' => 'email_address',
        // field name is "name", its value is defined by a PHP callback
        'name' => function () {
            return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
        },
    ];
}
// filter out some fields, best used when you want to inherit the parent implementation
// and blacklist some sensitive fields.
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    // remove fields that contain sensitive information
    unset($fields['auth_key'], $fields['password_hash'], $fields['password_reset_token']);
    return $fields;
}
```

more detail, refer to https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-resources.md

Answer (score 0):

You may use **scenarios** method inside your model for this, but you will have to extend a bit **toArray** method in order to make it work properly:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return array_merge(parent::scenarios(), [
        'simple_info' => [
            'email',
            'name',
        ],
        'login' => [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'auth_token',
        ],
    ]);
}

public function toArray(array $fields = array(), array $expand = array(), $recursive = true)
{
    $scenarios = $this->scenarios();
    $scenario = $this->getScenario();
    if (!empty($scenarios[$scenario])) {
        $data = parent::toArray($fields, $expand, $recursive);
        return array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($scenarios[$scenario]));
    }
    return parent::toArray($fields, $expand, $recursive);
}
```

After this you may simply do something like this:

```
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') && $model->login()) {
        $user = $model->getUser();
        // Lets change scenario to login in order to get `auth_token` for authorization
        $user->setScenario('login');
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save(FALSE);
        return $user;
    } else {
        return $model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note (expanding on the answer from @Ganiks), if you are manually returning the list of Models, you will need to return them as a DataProvider (rather than simply as an array of Models) for the `fields` parameter to have an effect.

For example, if you do something like this...

```
class UserController extends yii\rest\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return User::find()->all(); // Not what you want
    }

    // ...
}
```

... then the `fields` parameter will not have the desired effect. However, if you instead do this...

```
class UserController extends yii\rest\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => User::find(),
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

... then the returned fields will only be those you specified in the `fields` parameter.